# Swift - UIGraphics dash line close

Tags: swift, graphics, line

This is my code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width,graphSize), false, 0)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.3)
    CGContextBeginPath(context)
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, width1, height1)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, width11, height11)
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, width2, height2)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, width22, height22)
    //dash line
    CGContextStrokePath(context)
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, width3, height3)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, width33, height33)
    CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0, [4], 1)
    //next lines...
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, width4, height4)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, width44, height44)
```

I want to have dashes on width3 and height3, but my next lines are also dashed.. How to stop the dash line to be executed ?

Comment: You can try to reset it like this: `CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0, NULL, 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset the context like this:

```
CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0, nil, 0)
```